# How to locate sys_transcoder_queue table in MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

I'm having issues uploading a video to a UNA-based social media site. It seems to be an SMTP permissions issue. What command is used in terminal to locate 'sys_transcoder_queue' table?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a MySQL database from the Terminal can be done like this:

```
sudo mysql
```

This will connect you as `root` so long as you haven’t intentionally changed the default MySQL connection properties.

If you don’t know the name of the database containing the `sys_transcoder_queue` table, you can list them like this:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

With the name of the database known, you can now use it:

```
USE una_main;
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `una_main` with the actual database name.</sup>

Now you can query the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `sys_transcoder_queue` LIMIT 25;
```